# long running php script issue on firefox/IE

Tags: php

I am executing one php script, which is taking around 8  minutes to execute. this code is working fine on chrome, but on IE/Firefox it is not working. In the chrome, i am getting the output after 8 minutes, but in IE/Firefox i am not getting any response.

What could be issue? Please help on that. any issue with browser/header.

Comment: Reboot your computer. Reboot the server.

Comment: Can you please provide HTTP request and response headers in both cases? (use fiddler or wireshark to collect them).Or clear browser's chache/cookies/history.Try another PC, this will exclude problem with local installations of browsers.Also disable any noscript/adblocker addons.

Comment: Can't you queue this job for background processing using Gearman or something?

Comment: @hakre: Reboot the *server*? Seriously? Not everything is a Win95 box where a reboot is the way to solve most problems.

Comment: @Piskvor: Well with the detail of information given in the question, doing so would reduce the amount of temporary effects that might have been created by runtime both on the server as well as on the client side.

Comment: @hakre: Fair point; however, a request to reboot even a development server to shake out the bugs will probably bring you a "you want me to do WHAT?!?" anywhere - not to mention *live* servers (likely with SLAs). And to top it off, our dev servers have a boot time of several minutes - because they're not rebooted on every whim, five minutes' downtime once a month is acceptable, and fast boot is not a priority - *stable* boot is.

Comment: @Piskvor: I bet you're able to write better issue descriptions as well that don't need such a long "boot" time ;) I just wanted to suggest something which looked adequate in the light of the OP.

Comment: @hakre: Maybe, maybe not ;) I just feel that the "retry, reboot, reinstall" routine should be allowed to die, after all these years; encouraging it brings more harm than good (e.g. cargo cult debugging instead of trying to find the root of the issue).

Comment: my code stores all the values in array and at the end, i am doing export all these values in excel file. one thing i am not able understand why it is working in chrome but not working in firefox

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing? If it’s anything longer than a few seconds, you should let PHP manage it in the background and keep track of it through the Process ID – that keeps browser time out problems at bay, which is likely to be a problem and probably unsolvable.

Comment: thanks for you comment. I am  exporting  a report through php and mysql code which contains around 2 Lacs records. It is taking around 7 minutes to export all the records. Taking long time is not an issue. But i am not able to understand why this code is working on my local server and chrome browser. But not working on the development server. on both server php version is 5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating something like a long list of entries you may try pushing data that are already generated as you go by calling [flush](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php). This way browser will get some chunks of data now and then which should prevent it from timing out the connection.

But, generally speaking, script that runs 8 minutes doesn't seem like a good idea. Maybe there is a way you can generate the output with cron?

Comment: my code stores all the values in array and at the end, i am doing export all these values in excel file. one thing i am not able understand why it is working in chrome but not working in firefox

Comment: Probably because these browsers have a different timeout value for connections. For IE 8minutes is too long, for Chrome not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that some versions of IE (7 at least) will time out if no response is received within some time. There are several things you may want to try:

- move the heavy work into some background process, and poll for status/notify when done. This may require a lot of code restructuring, though.
- cache what you can - if you're generating a resource which might be usable next time, save the parts that don't need to be regenerated.
- Worst case hack/workaround: send the headers at the start of processing, plus some whitespace characters (test to see what amount works), and (if possible) send some whitespace once in some tens of seconds (and `flush()`). This should keep the client happy that *something* is going on; when processing finishes, send the result (or redirect to it, if leading whitespace is a concern).

Comment: my code stores all the values in array and at the end, i am doing export all these values in excel file. one thing i am not able understand why it is working in chrome but not working in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is probably dropping the connection after timing out. You PHP should give a reply in a matter of seconds (at most a minute). Anything long you have to either

1. Identify in the code why it is taking so long
2. If you cannot get the operation down to a reasonable time either give a reply and then perform the process or have a job queue and place the job in that queue for another process (PHP script?) to perform off line.

Try to go for (1) first as it is the simplest option.

Comment: i can't down the execution time  as well as can't perform offline.

Comment: thanks for you comment. I am exporting a report through php and mysql code which contains around 2 Lacs records. It is taking around 7 minutes to export all the records. Taking long time is not an issue. But i am not able to understand why this code is working on my local server and chrome browser. But not working on the development server. on both server php version is 5.1.6

Comment: @user1138143 - Make sure that the MySql queries are optomised (i.e. using the indexes). See EXPLAIN in the MySql documentation. Also profile your code to find out where it is taking so long. What are 2 Lacs BTW?

Comment: thanks, query is already very optimized. 2 lacs are records which  is coming from almost joining of 32 tables. So timing is not an issue. but please let me know if you can why it is working on one server and not working  on other .